# How to post an xml input with prefix in node in .net core

Tags: xml, .net-core

I need to post an xml which contains prefix in the root node to the controller. Here is the xml that I need to post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<star:SecuredFiles xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5">
<ED>2019-05-07T16:39:13Z</ED>
<AID/>
<SNC>U8</SNC>
<SID>sample</SID>
<RID>F37C6B44-FCA3-4313-A1E3-42EDB131FD17</RID>
<FileURI>9928645r01.pdf</FileURI>
<ServerGuid>PRUCTIONS</ServerGuid>
</star:SecuredFiles>
```

At controller I have code like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]SecuredFiles secureFile)
{
    ----------
}
```

I have the model class something like this:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5", IsNullable = false)]
    public class SecuredFiles
    {
        public DateTime ED { get; set; }
        public string AID { get; set; }
        public string SNC { get; set; }
        public string SID { get; set; }
        public string RID { get; set; }
        public string FileURI { get; set; }
        public string ServerGuid { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, when I am trying to POST this xml to the controller, I am getting null in the properties.

My Startup.cs looks something like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(opt =>
            {
                opt.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateModelStateAttribute)); // by type
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
                .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
------
}
```

Can somebody help to get it fixes please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by using this approach on controller..

```
            var body = string.Empty;
            SecuredFiles secureFile = new SecuredFiles(); ;
            Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
            {
                body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(body);
            var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("star", "http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5");

            string xpath = "star:SecuredFiles";
            var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath, nsmgr);
            // Read data from STAR xml
            foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
            {
                secureFile.AID = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//AID").InnerText;
                secureFile.ED = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//ED").InnerText;
                secureFile.FileURI = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//FileURI").InnerText;
                secureFile.RID = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//RID").InnerText;
                secureFile.ServerGuid = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//ServerGuid").InnerText;
                secureFile.SID = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//SID").InnerText;
                secureFile.SNC = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//SNC").InnerText;
            }
```

Thanks,